# Wrting Image in java in different formats gives different result

Tags: java, image

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        File original_f = new File(args[0]);
        String[] parts= args[0].split("\\.");
        String output_f = parts[0]+"_bin";
        original = ImageIO.read(original_f);
        grayscale = toGray(original);
        binarized = binarize(grayscale);            //Converts pixel of image in black((0,0,0)) or white( (255,255,255) )

        writeImage(output_f,parts[1]);

}   

private static void writeImage(String output, String part) throws IOException {
        File file = new File(output+".bmp");
        ImageIO.write(binarized, "bmp", file);
}
```

After binarizing  image  I'm getting correct answer. Pixel in binarized (variable in code) are either (0,0,0) or (255,255,255) .

But after writing Image in jpg format pixel are no longer correct, and if I  write image in bmp format then pixels are correct.

Can anyone please explain what could be the reason???

Comment: is this due to compression jpeg format?

Answer (score 1):

JPEG is **lossy** image compression file format. You just loose some accuracy of pixel color values due to lossy compression. Bitmap is **lossless** format but without compression. For lossless compression you can use PNG.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the JPEG encoder included with the Sun JDK then you must also ensure that you pass it an image with no alpha channel.